# Magento 1.6.2.0 - admin and frontend calling https URL's incorrectly

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have recently downloaded a site from my hosting server to my localhost. I have set up everything on localhost to use the local db, however when I run the frontend, the image files don't load as Magento is looking for them under `https://` instead of `http://`, the same goes for the entire back-end. The pages load in the backend but also no styles are applied as Magento is looking for them under `https://`. I'm not running **secure_url**, only **unsecure_url** on both back and frontend.

Here is a screenshot of Web Inspector.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this?

// edit

Well, my backend is a mess, here is a screenshot of the Config->Web section, specifically the URLs:

[image]

Comment: checkout `.htaccess` and `httpd.conf` - look for redirection rules.

Comment: What should I look for in `http.conf`? I don't see anything out of the ordinary with `.htaccess`, I have even loaded `.htaccess.sample`

Comment: look for `redirection rules` - you might find that requests for `http` are being redirected to `https`

Comment: My other localhost sites seem to work fine, they don't redirect or anything.

Comment: Don't use `localhost`. Use 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already emptied your `var/cache` folder, there is one other possible source for your problem.
Go to `System/Developer/` and disable `Javascript Settings/Merge JavaScript Files` and `CSS Settings/Merge CSS Files`. Then go to `System/Cache` and press the `Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache` button.

Comment: I can't click the `Save` button, it doesn't register when I click save.

Comment: So Javascript seems to be the problem! You have to edit this directly in the database using phpmyadmin or comparable. Go to table core_config_data and set dev/js/merge_files to 0

Comment: hm... you could then try to set the secure base url to http:// instead of https://. Only a temporary workaround but worth a try.

Comment: That worked! So somewhere it's the secure url is interfering?

Comment: Seems like. But the question is why. If not a caching or merging js/css issue, there's not much left concerning Magento itself. Then you should investigate in differences between live and dev environment.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it's a combination of my dev environment and the site itself. When I uploaded the exact same site to the hosting company's server, the url's worked correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to clear out var/cache if you haven't done so already. Do you have a trailing slash on your base_url too?

Comment: My answer is yes in both instances. Both haven't worked for me.

Comment: Have you checked the URL in the store scope as well?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by *store scope*? the store is located under `http://` but CSS &JS files load from `https://`

Comment: In the admin section, there's a dropdown list for all website/store views. There may have been a base_url set on one of the store fronts.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no redirection-rules that redirect HTTP->HTTPS in .htaccess or httpd.conf, 
you can also check the configuration in Magento:

```
Magento Admin area: Menu -> System -> Configuration -> Web
```

There, too, you can configure secure/non-secure connection

Comment: Everything looks fine in there, check my newest question edit. Also, clicking on Save does nothing when the backend is like this.

Comment: search for the `config.xml` and see if the file has "Write" permission

Comment: Does it need to be 777 or is 644 sufficient? I will have look as soon as I can,thanks.

Comment: On my server it's 644. the path is `MAGENTO_HOME/app/etc/config.xml`

Comment: I've just checked it out, it's 644.